# Run JNI Native Code as Root (Mac)

Tags: java, c, macos, java-native-interface, sudo

I've got some C code (.so file) that I call from a java app (JNI) that needs to be run as root.

Is there any way to make the .so file run as root (on a mac) without having to make the entire java app run as root?

Answer (score 1):

Native linked libraries are run in the process space of the linked application, so you will need to run the entire application as root for the native code to execute as root (you could however investigate [`chroot`](https://serverfault.com/questions/267227/why-is-chroot-never-used-on-mac-os-x)).